# How to find adjacent paths in SVG file?

Tags: html, algorithm, dictionary, svg, path

I am trying to make a clickable map game (like Risk) in which I have many  svg paths which is similar to this one:
[Example SVG Map](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/10/Brazil_Blank_Map.svg)

So when a player1 clicks a territory of player2 in order to attack it, the clicked territory should have border with player1's territory else attack is invalid.

I thought storing all the paths and it's neighboring paths in a multidimensional array like this:

```
path[0] -> path[0][0] path[0][1] path[0][2]
path[1] -> path[1][0] path[1][1]
```

**But since my map is huge, it is really inefficient for me to do it like this. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?**

Comment: What exactly is the problem? these paths you want to keep - from where to where do they go?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/hNpThyB.jpg So in this map. Player1 which has green territory should be able to attack yellow territory 2 but not 3 since Player1 doesn't have any borders with territory 3. My problem is that I need to find a way to prevent him from attacking territory 3.

Comment: Then all you need is an adjacency map. All you need to know is whether or not the territory about to be attacked has a neighbor the belongs to the attacking player...

Comment: Thanks but the problem is creating a adjacency map. My map is huge and storing the neighbouring paths for all my paths seems really unefficient to me.

Comment: You only need to store the adjacencies for each territory. Why use paths? Each territory has a list of neighbors. Even for a big map, that shouldn't be THAT much data (I think it's even `O(n)`...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**create country table**

Containing adjacency information, each country has usually up to 7 neighbors unless you have small states like Vatican, Luxemburg,... So for uniform map subdivision you can use static number of neighbors. Something like this:

- `int map[countries_max][neighbors_max];`

**Uniform map division**

There are more ways to obtain the adjacency info. For uniformly divided map you can compute average point of the border path which usually near center of country. Take each country point and find the closest countries (points) to it. If the distance is smaller then treshold store country index in neighbor list. The treshold can be around size of country (for rectangle division you need 2 treshold one per axis).

**generic map division**

You need to check if any part of country border path is near/parallel to any part of other country border path. If yes then store country index in neighbor list. This is doable only if you have the border paths.

**generic map division (no border paths)**

In case your map is raster or vector but not in form of closed polygons/paths per country (for example you can have division paths instead) then the above approaches are unusable. When you attack you know start and end position of attack so cast line from start to end (DDA or Bresenham) and count how many border lines you crossed (count the color edges). If the count is 1 move is valid. This will have false negatives if you cast attack crossing the same border multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the idea of using an array for this kind of thing is not the right way to follow.

*You should try to create a `class Map` and all the functions inside of this class would represent a territory and all the players would be objects of this class.*  Doing this, you can control the situation in a simpler way.

**For example:** to know if player1 already got that part of map, you will only need to see if the function `player1.Brazil` (where `Brazil` is the function inside the `class Map` of the object player1) is already with a flag = True. This flag would be a `boolean`, and whenever you get that territory you should change this flag to True.

So by comparing both, player's 1 and player's 2 functions with a simple `if` statement you can create a neighbouring paths that will respect the rules of the game.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But what if there were more than two players? We wouldn't find the neighbouring paths again.

Comment: @UlaşAnılAÇIKEL welcome my friend. Each player would be an object and each one of them would have their informations about the territories they already got, so it doesn't matter how many players you have, if you wanna discover if you can attack a specific part of the map, you would just need to call the fuctions of that part of the map, of each player, and compare with the logic of the game using a if statement. Of course this would be more and more difficult if you keep increasing the number of players. But that looks like a great algorithm for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have just come up with this. If I have a map in an svg element, each path is a country, and it has a 'data-code' attribute with the country code:

```
const map = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
```

First I create a map of points, instead of a "two dimensional array" (which is really an array of arrays, which I don't need) I just make an object with point keys in the form `(${x},${y})`, where however I also round the x and y coordinates not only to the nearest point but to the nearest point with even coordinates.

```
const points = {};

[...map.getElementsByTagName('path')].filter(p => p.attributes['data-code']).forEach(c => {
    const code = c.attributes['data-code'].value;
    const pathLength = c.getTotalLength();
    for(let length = 0; length < c.getTotalLength(); length++) {
        const point = c.getPointAtLength(length);
        const key = '('+2*Math.round(point.x/2)+','+2*Math.round(point.y/2)+')';
        (points[key] = points[key]||new Set()).add(code);
    }
});
```

and the value of these point keys in the points map are the sets of country codes which share this point.

Finally I extract the adjacencies from those points which are shared by more than one country:

```
const adjacencies = {};

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(points)
.map(p => points[p])
.filter(s => s.size > 1)
.forEach(s => {
    s.forEach(c => {
        const adj = adjacencies[c] = (adjacencies[c] || new Set());
        [...s].filter(cc => cc != c).forEach(ccc => adj.add(ccc))
        })
});
```

So in the end each country that has any adjacency will be in the adjacency map with the map value being the set of its adjacent countries.

I have a fairly sizeable world map and it has 8801 such even points, and 1651 shared even points.